# How to get keypress event in angular on Android?

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, keypress

How do we get the keypress event and its value in Angular on Android?
I Use the phonegap Cordova Angular JS

```
 <form name="myForm">
 <input type="search" name="userName" ng-model="user"  class="search-input" style="width: 96%; margin: 6px auto 6px auto;" placeholder="Начните вводить название">
 </form>
 </div>
 </div>
 user = {{user}}
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: ng-keypress="yourmethod(user)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <form name="myForm">
     <input type="search" 
            name="userName" 
            ng-model="user" 
            ng-keypress="yourMethod(user)" class="search-input" 
            style="width: 96%; margin: 6px auto 6px auto;" 
            placeholder="Начните вводить название">
 </form>

 user = {{user}}
```

**UPDATE:**

```
<input type="search" name="userName" ng-model="user" ng-change="getValue(user)" class="search-input" style="width: 96%; margin: 6px auto 6px auto;" placeholder="Начните вводить название">
```

And my controller `$scope.getValue = function (calll) { alert(calll); }`

Comment: ng-change="yourMethod(user)".

Comment: This is my input

        <input type="search" name="userName" ng-model="user"  ng-keydown="getValue(user)"  class="search-input" style="width: 96%; margin: 6px auto 6px auto;" placeholder="Начните вводить название">
    
And my controller

$scope.getValue = function (calll) {
alert(calll);
 }

but i see alert UNDEFINED

Comment: ng-model binds your view to controller.. ng-model="user" means the value you type in input box is the in user ..

Comment: I am facing same issue on android, tried `ng-change` but didn't work for me. https://stackoverflow.com/q/58113528/3081929

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name="myForm">
 <input type="search" name="userName" ng-keypress="getValue($event) ng-model="user"  class="search-input" style="width: 96%; margin: 6px auto 6px auto;" placeholder="Начните вводить название">
 </form>
 </div>
 </div>
 user = {{user}}


In controller :-

$scope.getValue = function (event) { console.log(event) }
```

Answer (score 0):

**ng-keypress** function available in angularjs,

You can also use **ng-keydown** and **ng-keyup** in similar manner. FYI.

For reference , 
[ng-keypress tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeypress)

Answer (score 0):

Creating a directive attribute might work better in this case.

```
angular.module('inputDirective', [])
    .directive("mydirective", function() {
        var directive = {};
        directive.restrict = 'A';
        directive.scope = {};
        directive.link = function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            //read the text typed in the div
            function read() {
                var html = element.html();
            }

            //do this whenever someone starts typing
            element.bind("keyup", function() {
                scope.$apply(read);
            });
        }

        return directive;
    })
```

In the html add the attribute to the  tag.

```
<input mydirective type="search" name="userName" ng-model="user"  class="search-input" style="width: 96%; margin: 6px auto 6px auto;" placeholder="Начните вводить название">
```