# Enter event doesn't trigger the function on Android device using angular

Tags: android, html, angular, cordova

There are multiple questions with answers related to my problem but unfortunately, none worked for me.

I have to detect the enter pressed on android keyboard and change focus from current matInput to next matInput.

I have tried `keyup.enter`, `keydown` and `keypress` but none worked for me. I implemented directive approach but doesn't trigger method when I am debugging app on Android device. Although, it does trigger the method on browser.

Here is what I am using.

**HTML:**

```
    <mat-form-field class="ib-input-container-width">
  <input matInput data-dependency="lastName" (keypress)="onChange($event.keyCode)" (keyup.enter)="handleNext('lastName')"  [formControl]="form.get('FirstName')" type="text" >

</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field class="ib-input-container-width" >
  <input #lastName id="lastName" matInput  [formControl]="form.get('LastName')" type="text">
```

**TS:**

```
  handleNext(elementId){
    let nextElement = document.getElementById(elementId);
    console.log(nextElement);
    nextElement.focus();
  }

  onChange(event){
    console.log(event.keycode);
  }
```

**PS:** I am on a working progressive web app using Cordova.

**Update**

I have tried solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/28103608/3081929
But ng-change doesn't work either.

Comment: Have you tried with `keydown` event, and checking what is the key code in TS?

Comment: I tried but it doesn't even trigger the method.

Comment: Hi, have you tried keyup?

 document.addEventListener('keyup', getInput, false);

function getInput(e){
   //your code
}

Comment: Tried that too and works perfect in browser but not in android. Method is not triggered.

Comment: Is the `keyup` event getting triggered when you use it without `enter` like this -> `(keyup)="handleNext('lastName')"`? Also the answer link in your question links to an angularjs solution. Did you try it using the `(change)` or `(input)` events?

Comment: Some time ago I made a "next-tab" directive, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53690973/change-behaviour-of-enter-key-in-a-phone-angular-5/53691367#53691367 that consist in put in the form `enter-tab` and in each control `#nextTab` and that I used in Android apk. Take a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the code looks correct,

before running your codova app on android make sure you have compiled the angular project using angular cli and output should be set to www folder

Comment: I was running the app directly, but didn't think about compiling again. Thanks for the suggestion.